# Cannot install cordova ionic on npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

**Anyone knows a way to fix this error?**

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g cordova ionic

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: pinkie-promise@^2.0.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS i5\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-01-06T21_18_22_900Z-debug.log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48132126/problems-with-npm-install-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `pinkie-promise`. Try this:

```
 $ npm install --save pinkie-promise@2.0.2
```