# Problems with npm install (Angular)

Tags: node.js, git, angular, npm

Today i try creat a new project. So i use this command:

```
ng new NAME --style=less
```

and in my cmder popped errors and warns.

So i unistall my node and files in Roaming/npm and npm-cache. Then I installed node and download again cmder. Then i try installed angular-cli and again warns and errors. When i try install webpack or git same.

This error and warn i have in logs:

```
1540 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: pinkie-promise@^2.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\read-pkg-up\node_modules\find-up\node_modules\pinkie-promise):

1541 warn 404 SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Not Found: pinkie-promise@^2.0.0

1542 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: pinkie-promise@^2.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\load-json-file\node_modules\pinkie-promise):

1543 warn 404 SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Not Found: pinkie-promise@^2.0.0

1551 error code ETARGET
1552 error notarget No matching version found for require-from-string@^1.1.0
1553 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
1553 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
1553 error notarget
1553 error notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'cosmiconfig'
1554 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little under a year ago, the package "leftpad" broke NPM builds all over the world because the author pulled it from the public repository.

The same is happening today, for "pinkie-promise". The author's NPM account (@floatdrop) was deleted, opening opportunities for malware in all the packages he's written.

Dependent builds include Ionic and (in my case) node-sass.

Resources:

- NPM issue: https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255
- Incident report: https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj
- pinkie-promise issue: https://github.com/floatdrop/pinkie-promise/issues/4
- Dependent packages: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/pinkie-promise
- All of @floatdrop's repositories: https://github.com/floatdrop?tab=repositories

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't know how but now it's everything okay i readed your answer and i tried one more time use npm install -g @angular/cli and everything its successfully.